# CMake Error variable not found LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR (Gate-9.0)

Tags: installation, geant4

So, I'm currently installing Gate-9.0 it's a simulation kit based on Geant4. I'm following the installation guide in the documents which uses the

```
ccmake ../Gate-9.0
```

When itry to configure, it gives me this CMake Error:

> 

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files: 
LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR(ADVANCED)
used as include directory in directory/home/art/Documents/Gate-9.0
used as include directory in directory /home/art/Documents/Gate-9.0
used as include directory in directory /home/art/Documents/Gate-9.0
```

I have the LIBXML2 library installed so i'm not really sure what to do. I'm not entirely familiar with linux-mint (and linux in general) so i appreciate any suggestions. Thanks! :)

Comment: is your libxml installed in a standard location?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the GATE 8.2 installation with optical photon applications. In ccmake, you need to press [t] to toggle advanced mode. There, you will have to find the lines that cause your problem:

```
*LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR      LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
*LIBXML2-LIBRARY          LIBXML2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
```

Change them to:

```
*LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR      (path_to_include)/include/libxml2
*LIBXML2-LIBRARY          (path_to_lib)/lib/libxml2.so
```

After that, you should be able to successfully configure, generate and compile.